# Setting GCM and APNS api key in azure notification hub through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, push-notification, notifications

I'm trying to provision a notification through powershell. I'm able to create a namespace and the hub but not able to set the GCM API key or add certificate to APNS provider. I'm using an input file to set values for notification hub. Below are the samples.

Powershell command to provision notification hub:

```
New-AzureRmNotificationHub -Namespace $Namespace  -ResourceGroup 
$ResourceGroupName -InputFile 
"D:Source\Deployment\NotificationConfiguration.json"
```

Json file content is as follows:

```
{
"Name": "LocalNotificationHub",
"Location": "West Europe",
"GcmCredential": {
"properties": {
  "googleApiKey":
    "<api key>",
  "gcmEndpoint": "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm able to create notification hub with name and location specified u=in the file but it is not taking the GCM credentials.

Thanks in advance.